# Why is creation of Clob tied to the Connection class?

Tags: java, soap, jdbc, connection, clob

I have a Java method which passes a CLOB to a PL/SQL procedure using JDBC. I was able to do that using the `createClob()` method of the `Connection` class.

Here is the [Java Doc for the Connection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). If you notice other than `createClob()` method there are also `createBlob()` , `createArrayOf()` , `createNClob()` methods in this class.

I am curious why the creation of instances of `Blob` ,  `Clob` , `NClob` is part of the `Connection` class ? It seems a bit out of place. Why should datatypes and its creation be tied to connection object ?

Why can't we create instances of these datatypes independently ? I am planning to expose this method with the following signature in a SOAP Web Services:

```
public String handleEmployeeReview(int empId , String fileName)
```

It seems little odd that a web service client would first have to create a `Connection` instance for creating a instance of `Clob`. (Unless there is another way of creating and passing Clobs that I am unaware of.)

Which also makes me wonder if my choice of `Clob` datatype for this method is the right one. Considering its being exposed in the web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC is designed to be database engine independent. The database types `INT`, `VARCHAR`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc., could have a more common implementation into Java types: `int`, `String`, `java.sql.Timestamp` which extends from `java.util.Date`, and on.

Data types like `BLOB`, `CLOB`, `NLOB` are more specific fields that can be implemented very differently in database engines, some database engines don't even support arrays as data type for table columns, but still JDBC should provide a transparent interface to communicate the client code and the database engine. The designers of JDBC interfaces thought that the creation of these objects should depend on the JDBC implementation (this is, a `CLOB` object is database engine specific), and the best place to provide the creation of `CLOB` objects (and similar) would be provided by the `java.sql.Connection` interface, since you at least need to open a physical database connection to create an instance of such specific database engine object. IMO this is the proper interface to do it, since it allows using the same `CLOB` object in different `PreparedStatement`s and `CallableStatement`s with no problems.

The usage of [`Connection#createClob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createClob--) method and similars should be used by your dao layer only. Other datasources may use a different approach to store binary data of your files e.g. a direct `byte[]` that is stored in memory, for this case the datasource would be a cache system, not a direct database.

Comment: I guess then I should not be exposing a method with Clob type parameter in the web service. I would need to use a database independent java type as a parameter and then create a Clob out of it under the hood.

Comment: @Twister yes, you should avoid using classes/interfaces like that to expose your services. Use primitive types, wrapper types, `String`, `BigDecimal`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Date` and arrays of one of these types only.